# Spring Boot add datasources at runtime?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, dynamic

I have a default database contains a table with column 'name' & 'jndi' means different datasources.

I can add data to this table at runtime.

How can I query datas from these datasources?

I have reference: https://www.codeday.top/2017/07/12/27122.html

But this sample seems need to predefine all the datasources.

Can somebody gives me some suggestions?

Comment: google it spring  JdbcTemplate

Comment: got it, thank you!

Comment: You are a great help!